# 'httpd-vhost.conf' breaks Wamp?

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost

This is my first post...

I am attempting to host a development website from my laptop using Wamp; my goal is to install Wordpress and have users log in from there homes...

- I've successfully installed Wamp 2.2.
- I've included `27.0.0.1 localhost` in my 'host' file.
- I've removed the `#` from the front of `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`.

`localhost` works perfectly until I edit my 'httpd-vhost.conf' file to include the following...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SeverAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot C:/Program Files/WampServer2/www
    ErrorLog "C:/Program Files/WampServer2/www/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/Program Files/WampServer2/www/logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Once I restart Wamp the icon stays orange. If I attempt to put Wamp online, an alert titled 'Aestan Tray Menu' stating "Could not execute menu item (internal error). [Exception] Could not preform service action: the service has not been started".

- Port 80 tested as "not actually used".

When I run 'httpd.exe' a command window opens then immediately closes before I can read it. I've tried various formats to `<VirtualHost *:80>` with no avail, however once I comment out my changes I am able to successfully restart Wamp and access `localhost`.

I haven't been able to find post about this problem anywhere! **Thanks!**

Comment: Go and have a look in the `error.log` at the configured path, and see if there's any useful error message in there.  I know nothing of how WAMP reports errors via its tray icon, but plenty about how to interpret Apache error logs.

Comment: The log file folder is empty @MichaelBerkowski. What could that mean?

Comment: Look around in the main httpd.conf to find out if any other log location has been configured. If it was starting correctly before, it sorta follows that there's going to be at least an empty log file somewhere.

Comment: I've found "apache_error.log"...

 `Child 10084: Child process is running` `Child 10084: Acquired the start mutex.` `Child 10084: Starting 64 worker threads.` `Child 10084: Starting thread to listen on port 80.` `Child 10084: Starting thread to listen on port 80.` `Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.` `Child 10084: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.` `Child 10084: Released the start mutex` `Child 10084: All worker threads have exited.` `Child 10084: Child process is exiting` `Parent: Child process exited successfully.`

Comment: Does it have any useful information in it?

Comment: Sorry.. Uhm, no? not to me at least. I've included the most recent entries above, though, they all seem to have been added at the time I had `<VirtualHost *:80>` commented out. There isn't any entries at the times I've un-commented `<VirtualHost *:80>` and unsuccessfully attempt to restart Wamp.

Comment: There is a line `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`

Comment: You say you've added 27.0.0.1 to your hosts, shouldn't that be 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is so complex. I know the original post is very old but just for those with a similar issue since I had it this morning.

To see the error, you run `httpd.exe` from within the command prompt. Just open a command prompt and then `cd` into the folder that contains `httpd.exe`, then type `httpd.exe` (i.e. don't just double click it from within the folder).

The result should tell you where the error lies. In my case, it was a syntax error inside the vhosts file.

Comment: Thanks this helped find my issue!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is the unquoted DocumentRoot with a space in it. Try:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SeverAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/WampServer2/www" # <- quotes added around this line
    ErrorLog "C:/Program Files/WampServer2/www/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/Program Files/WampServer2/www/logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This did not seem to help any @Sarah Kemp. And my error logs don't include any new entries from the attempt... Ugh, this is becoming increasingly frustrating.